# CDialog-based MFC application starts only in a primary monitor

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

Say, I am starting a CDialog-based MFC application from the Windows Explorer by double-clicking its executable file. It normally shows the dialog window in the center of the screen.

But if I move the Windows Explorer window into a secondary monitor and double-click it there, its window is still shown in the primary monitor.

How do I make it show in the monitor where the app is started from?

PS. The dialog window is shown from `InitInstance` as such:

```
CTestMFCDlg dlg;
m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
```

Comment: (food for thoughts) where do you expect it to show up if run from "startup" entry in Start menu? From a "Run" entry in registry? From a command line?...

Comment: @YePhIcK: In that case it will open up in the primary monitor. But if someone double-clicks it in the Windows Explorer in a secondary monitor and it opens up in the primary one, this is quite confusing especially if it's a pair of large screens. Moreover the window manager seems to open a plain Win32-based GUI app in the monitor where it was run from the Explorer, if `CW_USEDEFAULT` flags were specified for `x` and `y`. So there must be something missing in the MFC implementation...

Comment: You could detect on which monitor the mouse pointer is and center your window on that monitor in `OnInitDialog`.

Answer (score 3):

OK. I got it. Nevermind.

Whoever else is interested, MFC has no concept of multiple monitors. So one needs to override the centering method as such:

```
void CTestMFCDlg::CenterWindowSmart()
{
    //Try to get the monitor that the process was started in
    STARTUPINFO si = {0};
    ::GetStartupInfo(&si);
    MONITORINFO mi = {0};
    mi.cbSize = sizeof(mi);
    if(::GetMonitorInfo((HMONITOR)si.hStdOutput, &mi))
    {
        //Got monitor size & position where the process was started in
        CRect rcThis;
        this->GetWindowRect(rcThis);

        int x = ((mi.rcWork.right - mi.rcWork.left) - rcThis.Width()) / 2;
        int y = ((mi.rcWork.bottom - mi.rcWork.top) - rcThis.Height()) / 2;

        this->MoveWindow(mi.rcWork.left + x, mi.rcWork.top + y, rcThis.Width(), rcThis.Height());
    }
    else
        this->CenterWindow();
}
```

Based on the remarks for the [STARTUPINFO structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331(v=vs.85).aspx) (search for `HMONITOR`.)